# Manifest homepage_url and ExtensionInfo.hompageUrl

Tags: opera-extension

It says in the Opera API (Formats: Manifest Files):

> homepage_url
>
> The URL of the homepage for this extension. The extensions management page will contain a link to this URL. *If you distribute your extension using the Opera addons site, the homepage URL defaults to the extension's own page*.

But from using `ExtensionInfo.hompageUrl`, those extensions without `homepage_url` in manifest will just give blank instead of its Opera addons site url.

On Chrome's side it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. I've just reported that. Thank you for the info!

Comment: By the way `showConfirmDialog` isn't working for `chrome.management.uninstall` too.